# How can I post one page variable data to two different pages with POST construct?

Tags: php, html

I have used below code in my present page to transfer data from present page to Save.php.I also want to post data to one more page .How can it be done?

```
<form method="post" action="Save.php">
```

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Why do you want to send data to other page?

Comment: I want to use a variable which is taken as input in the previous page

Comment: You can set sessions and can redirect to other page and then use that session in that page

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
<?php
session_start();?>
```

HTML CODE HERE....

```
<?php
$_SESSION['varname']=$savedvalue;//value you want to save
?>
```

save the html file to pagename.php
then in the save.php page again use sessions

```
<?php
    session_start();
$storedval=$_SESSION['varnmame'];
//the above line takes value stored in session variable and puts it in the storedval variable
?>
```

you could use same code above at any page and retrieve the valus stored in session variable

Comment: Trying your suggestion I tried <?php
 session_start(); 
$_SESSION['num']=$number; 
 ?>
<html>
<body>
 <form method="post" >
  Enter the number of questions <input type="text" name="number"/><hr/>
  <input type="submit" value="Store in session variable" onclick="retrieve.php"/>
 </form>
 </body>
</html> in one file and <?php  
 session_start(); 
echo "Welcome ".$_SESSION['num']."<br/>";

?> in retrieve.php But its not working. Error is Notice: Undefined variable: number in C:\xampp\htdocs\RB.php on line 3

Comment: save the session variable inside your retrieve.php file.you need to get the value using $number=$_POST['number'];and then you can save it inside the session variable.the error u have there is because there is no value assigned for the variable number.